# Displaying db table row that matches WP post-id

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress

Need some guidance. I've built a volleyball club site in Wordpress and we've solicited player profile data that I'm capturing in a Google form/spreadsheet, saving as a .csv then importing into a custom table called 'profiles'. http://goo.gl/05tu3O

I'm attempting to add code to the player template file to display the data in an html table, based on a match of the WP post-id. http://goo.gl/5bvwzV

I determined all the player page post-ids and included them in the first column of the table called "post_id", and set it as Primary. The goal is, if you open a player page with postid-1566 for example, the row in the profiles table with a post_id of 1566 should be displayed.

What I've got now pulls up everyone's profile data because of the SELECT * query. I'm trying to change the syntax of the query to DISTINCT so it looks for the specific row in the profile table that has the same post-id number as the player page you're on.

```
<?php
  global $wpdb;
//  $result = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare ( "SELECT DISTINCT $wpdb->posts.ID FROM $wpdb->profiles" ) );
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare ( "SELECT * FROM profiles" ) );

    foreach ( $result as $print )   {

      echo '<h6>Playing Experience </h6><p>' . $print->PlayingExperience.'</p>';
      echo '<h6>Previous Clubs </h6><p>' . $print->PreviousClubs.'</p>';
      echo '<h6>Athletic Awards & Accolades</h6><p>' . $print->AwardsAccolades.'</p>';
      echo '<h6>Fondest Volleyball Memory</h6><p>' . $print->FondestMemory.'</p>';
      echo '<h6>Best Finish</h6><p>' . $print->BestFinish.'</p>';
      echo '<h6>Online Video</h6><p>' . $print->OnlineVideo.'</p>';

      echo '<h3>Profile Details</h3>';

//      echo '[content_protector password="xxxxxxx" cookie_expires="0" identifier="xxx"]';
//      echo '[content_protector password=&quot;xxxxxxx&quot; cookie_expires=&quot;0&quot; identifier=&quot;xxx&quot;]';

// In case there is opening and closing shortcode.
//      echo do_shortcode( '[content_protector password="xxxxxxx" cookie_expires="0" identifier="xxx"] Private Info  [/content_protector]' );
      echo do_shortcode( '[content_protector password="xxxxxxx" cookie_expires="0" identifier="xxx"]' );
      echo '<h2>' . $print->FirstName.' ' . $print->LastName.' </h2>';
      echo '<table class="profile center">';
      echo '<tr><td>Team </td><td>' . $print->Team.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>First Name </td><td>' . $print->FirstName.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Nickname </td><td>' . $print->Nickname.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Middle Name </td><td>' . $print->MiddleName.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Last Name </td><td>' . $print->LastName.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Height </td><td>' . $print->Height.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Position </td><td>' . $print->Position.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Birthday </td><td>' . $print->Birthday.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>School </td><td>' . $print->School.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Grade </td><td>' . $print->Grade.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Class </td><td>' . $print->Class.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Commitment </td><td>' . $print->Commitment.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Standing Reach </td><td>' . $print->Reach.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Block Touch </td><td>' . $print->Block.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Approach Jump </td><td>' . $print->Approach.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>GPA (Unweighted) </td><td>' . $print->GPA_Unweighted.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>GPA (Weighted) </td><td>' . $print->GPA_Weighted.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Class Rank </td><td>' . $print->ClassRank.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>ACT Scores </td><td>' . $print->ACT_Score.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>SAT Scores </td><td>' . $print->SAT_Score.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Parents / Guardians </td><td>' . $print->Parents.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Parent 1 Email </td><td>' . $print->ParentEmail1.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Parent 2 Email </td><td>' . $print->ParentEmail2.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Address </td><td>' . $print->Address.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>City, State, Zip </td><td>' . $print->City.', ' . $print->State.', ' . $print->Zip.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Your Cell # </td><td>' . $print->YourCell.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Parent 1 Cell # </td><td>' . $print->ParentCell1.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Parent 2 Cell # </td><td>' . $print->ParentCell2.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Home Phone </td><td>' . $print->HomePhone.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Interest in Beach Volleyball? </td><td>' . $print->BeachInterest.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Beach Volleyball experience? </td><td>' . $print->BeachExperience.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Next ACT/SAT date </td><td>' . $print->NextACTSATdate.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Favorite Subjects </td><td>' . $print->FavoriteSubjects.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Desired Area of Study </td><td>' . $print->DesiredMajor.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Desired Level of Play </td><td>' . $print->DesiredPlayingLevel.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>State of College Preference </td><td>' . $print->CollegePreference.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Size of School </td><td>' . $print->SchoolSize.'</td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td>Contacting schools? </td><td>' . $print->ContactingSchools.'</td></tr>';
      echo '</table>';
//      echo '[/content_protector]';
      echo do_shortcode( '[/content_protector]' );

  }
?>
```

Not sure if I'm approaching this the best way, but feel I'm close. I think the solution is somewhere in this example but I can't get it to work.

```
$result = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare ( "SELECT DISTINCT $wpdb->posts.ID FROM $wpdb->profiles WHERE post_id = $postid" ) );
```

Also having trouble executing the closing tag of the "content_protector" shortcode. I can get it started with the do_shortcode, but everything past that needs to be inside that [/content_protector] and it doesn't work adding the last half of that line to the bottom. Any suggestions? Is there maybe a way to nest everything between the shortcode?

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Why do you need DISTINCT when you limit your results by post id?  Is post id not unique in the profiles table?  In other words, does `SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE post_id = $postid` return more than 1 record?

Comment: Was just trying something different. Yes, post id is unique... only one row per player. The page still renders with this, but doesn't return anything. Thx though!

Comment: @devlin, you were right... I just needed to add $postid = get_the_ID(); to the top and it works! Woo hoo! 

Now I just need to get the ending content_protector shortcode to work so I can hide this personal data via password. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select DISTINCT doesn't make sense to me. In you profiles table, each entry/row is already unique, right? One player per row? [DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) would return any repeating values only one time.

I think you want something like this

```
$print = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare ( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->profiles 
                                            WHERE post_id = %s," $postid) );
```

Skip using $result and looping through each result. Each result from get_row should contain the entire row of player data. Instead loop through each player with their ID and query the entire row.

```
foreach ($postids as $postid){

    $print = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare ( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->profiles 
                                               WHERE post_id = %s," $postid) );
    // echo all those print lines
}
```

Comment: This approach that i'm thinking about is assuming that you somehow are getting the $postid(s) for the players that you want to display data for. Would the postids be in an array that you previously have? Or on each page load, do you populate the `$postid` variable with the ID of the player that you want to display?

Comment: Yeah, each entry/row is unique, one player per row. Those suggestions won't render the page, just a white screen. Looks like it should work though. Not sure about your questions but I would lean to the latter. I'm a designer/webmaster just trying to make this work so forgive my ignorance. I can change the name of the column from post_id to something else if that helps. Many thx for the suggestion!

Comment: Check the error log to see what the PHP error says. If you need to, set in wp-config.php to display errors like so. `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);`

Comment: `$wpdb->prepare ( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->profiles  WHERE post_id = %s," $postid)` is what you are looking for. This should return every column for the specific row where $postid equals the player's post_id. That way you can -> for LastName, MiddleName, School, ect.. The question is, where are you getting the ID from? Will each page be displaying just one player? aka. you could get the player's ID with the wordpress method `get_the_ID()` [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/)

Comment: Says... Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$postid' (T_VARIABLE).  Yeah, that's exactly what needs to happen. And yes, each page is displaying one player. I read some things about get_the_ID() but not sure how to implement it.

Comment: If I add the get_the_ID() it returns...  Cannot redeclare get_the_ID() (previously declared in .../dev.tavhouston.com/wp-includes/post-template.php. Probably need different code before adding this, or it needs to go in functions.php since it's a function.

Comment: This works...

    `$postid = get_the_ID(); 
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare ( "SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE post_id = $postid" ) );
    foreach ( $result as $print )   {`

Now I just need to get the ending shortcode working and it's done. Any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 0):

Got it! This works...

```
$postid = get_the_ID(); 
$result = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare ( "SELECT * FROM profiles 
                                               WHERE post_id = $postid" ) ); 
foreach ( $result as $print ) {
```

And the shortcode trick with lots of code in the middle of the open/close tags is:

```
$the_content = '<h2>' . $print->FirstName.' ' . $print->LastName.' </h2>';
$the_content .= '<table class="profile center">';
$the_content .= '<tr><td>Team </td><td>' . $print->Team.'</td></tr>';
$the_content .= '<tr><td>First Name </td><td>' . $print->FirstName.'</td></tr>';
$the_content .= '<tr><td>Nickname </td><td>' . $print->Nickname.'</td></tr>';
$the_content .= '<tr><td>Middle Name </td><td>' . $print->MiddleName.'</td></tr>';
$the_content .= '<tr><td>Last Name </td><td>' . $print->LastName.'</td></tr>';
...
$the_content .= '/<table>';
echo do_shortcode( '[content_protector password="xxxxxxx" cookie_expires="0" identifier="xxx"]' . $the_content . '[/content_protector]' );
```

Thx guys for helping me find the solution. You rock!